# Foreach Counter Broken - Lists to many of the same row

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here is the code, and this code is producing the following output:  [screenshot of output](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0322g4jj8b)

the idea is to have a different header everytime the number of beds changes.

```
$tableTop = '<table> ... <tbody>';
$tableBottom = '</tbody> </table>';

$last_bed = null;

foreach ($unitsForSaleData as $row) {
    if($units_for_sale['beds'] == 0){
    if ($last_bed == null) {
        echo '<h1> Studios For Sale </h1>';
        echo $tableTop;
        $last_bed = $units_for_sale['beds'];
        }

    } else {
        if ($units_for_sale['beds'] !== $last_bed) {
            if ($last_bed !== null) { // End previous table
                echo $tableBottom;
            }
            echo '<h1>'.$units_for_sale['beds'].' Bedroom Condos For Sale </h1>';
            echo $tableTop; // Start new table
            $last_bed = $units_for_sale['beds'];
        }
    }

?>
<tr> ... </tr>

<?php 
} // end loop
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the array you are looping over?

Comment: How do you mean?  I added a more detailed look at the code.  The issue is that the every item in the first block gets its own table around it.  See screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with an `isset` instead of an `== null`.  Here is the full code for anyone else who needs something like this done:

```
$tableTop = '<table> ... <tbody>';
$tableBottom = '</tbody> </table>';

$last_bed = null;

foreach ($unitsForSaleData as $row) {
    if($units_for_sale['beds'] == 0){
    if (!isset($last_bed)) {
        echo '<h1> Studios For Sale </h1>';
        echo $tableTop;
        $last_bed = $units_for_sale['beds'];
        }

    } else {
        if ($units_for_sale['beds'] !== $last_bed) {
            if ($last_bed !== null) { // End previous table
                echo $tableBottom;
            }
            echo '<h1>'.$units_for_sale['beds'].' Bedroom Condos For Sale </h1>';
            echo $tableTop; // Start new table
            $last_bed = $units_for_sale['beds'];
        }
    }

?>
<tr> ... </tr>

<?php 
} // end loop
```

Comment: I would advise empty() instead of !isset() as it returns TRUE on a wider range of empty values.